# Service 200A, 220V into a 4 apt bldg. 1 apt only has 120. Voltmeter reads 220 across 2legs into meter, but out of the meter it is 120. what's wrong?

Tags: meter

Power to the Utility meter has two legs 120V each, but as it comes out of the meter into the panel only one leg has 120 the other one is zero.  where is the problem here?

Comment: Broken wire or wire is not connected at one end.  That or the meter is not passing current on one side.  Since these wires are always live(to the owner) caution is advised.

Comment: I confirmed that the meter is not passing current on one side.  so, the question is how to repair it? I called the utility, but they say it is not for them to resolve.  I asked for a meter replacement and they say that it is not necessary.  what to do?

Comment: In most places the meter belongs to the utility/power company and you are not suppose to touch it.  Most places also have a government department/section/over sight over the power companies.  It could be the meter is okay, but the wire coming from it is not connected right to the meter, this might up to your electrician to fix.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires a licensed electrician to do electrical work on a rental property in the US (assumed by references to 120V) and is not, therefore, a DIY project.

Answer (score 2):

The meter does belong to the power company but in most cases, the meter cans do not and it's the responsibility of the customer to maintain/ replace the meter can when required. If there's good voltage going into the meter but bad/no voltage coming out, the meter can is more than likely at fault. So an electrician would be required to replace the blocks of the meter or the entire can. Many power companies will allow an electrician to pull the meter and fix/replace the can. Other's don't and require you to call them and they'll send out a crew to pull it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if the fault is with the meter, or the *"meter pan"* aka mounting/enclosure.

Step 1. Get your electrician's license. Non-licensed individuals are NOT allowed to work on rental properties, and they're NOT allowed to work on multi-unit buildings. (you're welcome to burn down your own single-family residence, but not other people's stuff).  This is a *trade*, and it takes about 5 years of trade school and apprenticing under a master to get a license.

Oh good. You're back.

Step 2. Contact the power company and tell them you'll be pulling the meter pan to check for faults behind the meter. You'll be breaking their seal, and they need to give you permission to do that. They'll send someone out in a few weeks to re-seal the meter. If you don't tell them in advance, they will accuse you of bypassing the meter to steal power.

Step 3. Break the seal, pull the meter and visually and test-meter inspect the meter pan for faults. Also inspect the meter.  Since you are a licensed electrician at this step, I hardly need to tell you all this stuff is "hot all the time" and can go very, very BOOM IN YOUR FACE if you are not careful.

Step 4: If the meter pan is faulty, contact them to have them send out a bucket truck to pull the service drop wires off their wires.  Then replace the meter pan, and have them come out to reconnect and reinstall the meter.

Step 5: If the meter pan is fine, do your testing to see if there's anything you just missed... then call them back and tell them the meter is definitely bad.